# Trigonometric simplification .Correct syntax?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, syntax, algebraic-manipulation

I cannot simplify this expression any further, which should result in 7.
Could you please provide me with the correct syntax, I have tried several without success.

$$Assumptions[A + B + C == 0 , 
 TrigReduce[\frac {\cot A + 2\tan B} {\tan B} + \frac {\cot B + 
      3\tan C} {\tan C} + \frac {\cot C + \tan A} {\tan A}]]$$

Edit

```
Assumptions[A + B + C == 0 , 
TrigReduce[(Cot [A] + 2*Tan [B])/Tan [B] + (Cot [B] + 3*Tan [C])/
Tan [C] + (Cot [C] + Tan [A])/Tan [A]]]
```

Edit 2
I made a mistake when copying the code ,sorry

```
Assumptions[A + B + C == 180 , 
TrigReduce[(Cot [A] + 2*Tan [B])/Tan [B] + (Cot [B] + 3*Tan [C])/
Tan [C] + (Cot [C] + Tan [A])/Tan [A]]]
```

Comment: please post in plain text the Mathematica code that you used. You are using Latex there it seems. Not the actual Mathematica code you used.

Comment: `((Cot[a] + 2 Tan[b])/Tan[b] + (Cot[b] + 3 Tan[c])/
     Tan[c] + (Cot[c] + Tan[a])/Tan[a]) /. {c -> -(a + b)} // Simplify`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon ,I made a mistake when copying the code ,sorry : following your idea I made this but it doesn't work    ((Cot[a] + 2 Tan[b])/Tan[b] + (Cot[b] + 3 Tan[c])/      Tan[c] + (Cot[c] + Tan[a])/Tan[a]) /. {c -> 180-(a + b)} // Simplify

Comment: `(Cot[A] + 2*Tan[B])/Tan[B] + (Cot[B] + 3*Tan[C])/Tan[C] + (Cot[C] + Tan[A])/Tan[A] /. C -> 180 Degree - (A + B) // Simplify`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon ,Thank you very much for your time, I got lost between degrees and radians.

Comment: Also, `Assumptions` is not a valid command, you should look in docs for `Assuming`

Comment: In general, the use of uppercase letters is reserved for pre-defined symbols in Mma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
TrigReduce[(Cot[A] + 2*Tan[B])/Tan[B] + (Cot[B] + 3*Tan[C])/
     Tan[C] + (Cot[C] + Tan[A])/Tan[A]] /. {C -> -A - B} // Simplify
```

Comment: I made a mistake when copying the code ,sorry , following your idea I made this but it doesn't work TrigReduce[(Cot[A] + 2*Tan[B])/Tan[B] + (Cot[B] + 3*Tan[C])/
     Tan[C] + (Cot[C] + Tan[A])/Tan[A]] /. {C ->180 -A - B} // Simplify

Comment: `TrigReduce[(Cot[A] + 2*Tan[B])/Tan[B] + (Cot[B] + 3*Tan[C])/
     Tan[C] + (Cot[C] + Tan[A])/Tan[A]] /. {C -> \[Pi] - A - 
     B} // Simplify`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I got lost between degrees and radians.